# How to write in-memory PCM data by using IMFSinkWriter?

Tags: c++, com, ms-media-foundation

Hi every great hackers.

I can mix the audio and the video data that are read from files by using IMFSinkWriter, but I can't find how to mix raw PCM data in memory to the final media file by using IMFSinkWriter.

I suppose that in-memory raw PCM data will be generated by any methods.

I used the setting below for sinkwriter and the target audio format is MP3.

```
hr = writer->AddStream(mt_aud_in, &speech_stream_ind);
mytrace(L"speech_stream_ind = %d\n", speech_stream_ind);
HRTrace(hr); 

hr = MFCreateMediaType(&mt_aud_speech);
HRTrace(hr); 
hr = mt_aud_speech->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Audio);
HRTrace(hr); 
hr = mt_aud_speech->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFAudioFormat_PCM);
HRTrace(hr); 
hr = mt_aud_speech->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, 2);
HRTrace(hr); 
hr = mt_aud_speech->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, 44100);
HRTrace(hr); 
hr = mt_aud_speech->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, 16);
HRTrace(hr); 
hr = writer->SetInputMediaType(speech_stream_ind, mt_aud_speech, NULL);
HRTrace(hr);
```

Regards,

Comment: Prepare media types, initialize sink writer, create samples with data, feed them into the writer, get the file. It's straightforward. Show your code if you have problems on the way.

Comment: Media Foundation's error message said ' No suitable transform was found to encode or decode the content'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by setting MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND attribute.

The resolver that Sink Writer will use needs this attribute.

But MSDN is not saying this important thing.

```
HRESUlT hr = MFCreateMediaType(&mt_aud_speech_in);
hr = mt_aud_speech_in->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Audio);
hr = mt_aud_speech_in->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFAudioFormat_PCM);
hr = mt_aud_speech_in->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, 2);
hr = mt_aud_speech_in->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, 16);
hr = mt_aud_speech_in->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
hr = mt_aud_speech_in->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, 44100);
hr = mt_aud_speech_in->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND, 44100*2*2);
```

Comment: Thank you for updating your question. This saved me many hours.